# How to write additional description under a table

Tags: tables

I want to add additional description (with small fonts) under a table. An example is as follows:
[image]

I want to add "This table shows the type of X-ray analysis performed. ..."

Comment: Simply add another row with `\multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{...contents...}}`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [`ctable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
  botcap,
  caption={The caption for this table},
  label=test,
  notespar
]{*4c l c}{
\tnote[]{Some test text for the example test text for the example test text for the example text for the example}
}{
\toprule
Header1 & Header1 & Header1 & Header1 & Header1 & Header1 \\
\midrule
Text1 & Text1 & Text1 & Text1 & Text1 & Text1 \\
\bottomrule
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.  First, but the tabular content into a box.  Then, measure the width of the box.  Then create a `\parbox` of the same width to place the under-text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\tempbox
\newlength\templen
\begin{document}
\sbox\tempbox{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
This & is a & test\\
\hline
of the & emergency broadcast & system\\
\hline
This is & only a & test\\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\setlength\templen{\wd\tempbox}
\begin{table}
\centering
\usebox{\tempbox}\\[3pt]
\parbox{\the\templen}{\small This table shows the type of X-ray analysis performed\ldots}
\caption{Here is my table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]